# Lubuntu vs Windows 10 - default firewall - default settings

Tags: networking, lubuntu, firewall

The results scanned from the third device connected to the same private network with the two devices in discussion, Lubuntu and Windows 10:

The first scanned device, with Lubuntu(`Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS`) installed on it, with default firewall settings:

```
    nmap -p 1-65535 192.168.100.7 -vvv                                130 ⨯
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-02-02 15:58 EST
Initiating Ping Scan at 15:58
Scanning 192.168.100.7 [2 ports]
Completed Ping Scan at 15:58, 0.00s elapsed (1 total hosts)
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 15:58
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 15:58, 0.00s elapsed
DNS resolution of 1 IPs took 0.00s. Mode: Async [#: 1, OK: 0, NX: 1, DR: 0, SF: 0, TR: 1, CN: 0]
Initiating Connect Scan at 15:58
Scanning 192.168.100.7 [65535 ports]
Discovered open port 11393/tcp on 192.168.100.7
Discovered open port 39457/tcp on 192.168.100.7
Discovered open port 55628/tcp on 192.168.100.7
Discovered open port 62408/tcp on 192.168.100.7
Discovered open port 30630/tcp on 192.168.100.7
Discovered open port 36629/tcp on 192.168.100.7
Completed Connect Scan at 15:58, 1.78s elapsed (65535 total ports)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.100.7
Host is up, received conn-refused (0.00016s latency).
Scanned at 2021-02-02 15:58:03 EST for 2s
Not shown: 65529 closed ports
Reason: 65529 conn-refused
PORT      STATE SERVICE REASON
11393/tcp open  unknown syn-ack
30630/tcp open  unknown syn-ack
36629/tcp open  unknown syn-ack
39457/tcp open  unknown syn-ack
55628/tcp open  unknown syn-ack
62408/tcp open  unknown syn-ack

Read data files from: /usr/bin/../share/nmap
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.87 seconds
```

The second scanned device with Windows 10 installed on it, with default firewall settings:

```
nmap -Pn 1-65535 192.168.100.11 -vvv                              130 ⨯
Host discovery disabled (-Pn). All addresses will be marked 'up' and scan times will be slower.
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-02-02 16:07 EST
Warning: Hostname 1-65535 resolves to 2 IPs. Using "ISP ".
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 2 hosts. at 16:07
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 2 hosts. at 16:07, 0.00s elapsed
DNS resolution of 2 IPs took 0.00s. Mode: Async [#: 1, OK: 1, NX: 1, DR: 0, SF: 0, TR: 2, CN: 0]
Initiating Connect Scan at 16:07
Scanning 2 hosts [1000 ports/host]
Discovered open port 80/tcp on "ISP IP"
Completed Connect Scan against "ISP IP"in 12.47s (1 host left)
Completed Connect Scan at 16:07, 12.66s elapsed (2000 total ports)
Nmap scan report for 1-65535 ("ISP IP")
Host is up, received user-set (0.0078s latency).
Other addresses for 1-65535 (not scanned): "ISP IP"
rDNS record for "ISP IP": "ISP IP"
Scanned at 2021-02-02 16:07:05 EST for 13s
Not shown: 999 filtered ports
Reason: 999 no-responses
PORT   STATE SERVICE REASON
80/tcp open  http    syn-ack

Nmap scan report for 192.168.100.11
Host is up, received user-set.
All 1000 scanned ports on 192.168.100.11 are filtered because of 1000 no-responses

Read data files from: /usr/bin/../share/nmap
Nmap done: 2 IP addresses (2 hosts up) scanned in 12.76 seconds
```

The public IP from the output was replaced with "ISP IP"

Can anyone say please, why there are so many open ports for the default Firewall settings in Lubuntu then in Windows 10? Thank you.

EDIT:
For Lubuntu machine:

```
sudo ss -tulp
Netid     State      Recv-Q     Send-Q         Local Address:Port            Peer Address:Port     Process                                                                                            
udp       UNCONN     0          0                    0.0.0.0:43611                0.0.0.0:*         users:(("avahi-daemon",pid=441,fd=14))                                                            
udp       UNCONN     0          0                224.0.0.251:mdns                 0.0.0.0:*         users:(("chrome",pid=2008,fd=135))                                                                
udp       UNCONN     0          0                    0.0.0.0:mdns                 0.0.0.0:*         users:(("avahi-daemon",pid=441,fd=12))                                                            
udp       UNCONN     0          0              127.0.0.53%lo:domain               0.0.0.0:*         users:(("systemd-resolve",pid=431,fd=12))                                                         
udp       UNCONN     0          0                    0.0.0.0:631                  0.0.0.0:*         users:(("cups-browsed",pid=4799,fd=7))                                                            
udp       UNCONN     0          0                          *:11393                      *:*         users:(("outline-ss-serv",pid=1568,fd=8))                                                         
udp       UNCONN     0          0                          *:36629                      *:*         users:(("outline-ss-serv",pid=1568,fd=10))                                                        
udp       UNCONN     0          0                       [::]:mdns                    [::]:*         users:(("avahi-daemon",pid=441,fd=13))                                                            
udp       UNCONN     0          0                          *:30630                      *:*         users:(("outline-ss-serv",pid=1568,fd=12))                                                        
udp       UNCONN     0          0                          *:55628                      *:*         users:(("outline-ss-serv",pid=1568,fd=14))                                                        
udp       UNCONN     0          0                          *:6666                       *:*         users:(("qlipper",pid=1156,fd=13))                                                                
udp       UNCONN     0          0                          *:39457                      *:*         users:(("outline-ss-serv",pid=1568,fd=16))                                                        
udp       UNCONN     0          0                       [::]:56865                   [::]:*         users:(("avahi-daemon",pid=441,fd=15))                                                            
tcp       LISTEN     0          4096           127.0.0.53%lo:domain               0.0.0.0:*         users:(("systemd-resolve",pid=431,fd=13))                                                         
tcp       LISTEN     0          5                  127.0.0.1:ipp                  0.0.0.0:*         users:(("cupsd",pid=4798,fd=7))                                                                   
tcp       LISTEN     0          4096               127.0.0.1:9050                 0.0.0.0:*         users:(("tor",pid=563,fd=6))                                                                      
tcp       LISTEN     0          4096               127.0.0.1:9090                 0.0.0.0:*         users:(("prometheus",pid=1555,fd=8))                                                              
tcp       LISTEN     0          511                127.0.0.1:9091                 0.0.0.0:*         users:(("node",pid=1540,fd=19))                                                                   
tcp       LISTEN     0          4096               127.0.0.1:9092                 0.0.0.0:*         users:(("outline-ss-serv",pid=1568,fd=3))                                                         
tcp       LISTEN     0          4096                       *:36629                      *:*         users:(("outline-ss-serv",pid=1568,fd=9))                                                         
tcp       LISTEN     0          5                      [::1]:ipp                     [::]:*         users:(("cupsd",pid=4798,fd=6))                                                                   
tcp       LISTEN     0          4096                       *:39457                      *:*         users:(("outline-ss-serv",pid=1568,fd=15))                                                        
tcp       LISTEN     0          4096                       *:11393                      *:*         users:(("outline-ss-serv",pid=1568,fd=7))                                                         
tcp       LISTEN     0          4096                       *:30630                      *:*         users:(("outline-ss-serv",pid=1568,fd=11))                                                        
tcp       LISTEN     0          511                        *:62408                      *:*         users:(("node",pid=1540,fd=22))                                                                   
tcp       LISTEN     0          4096                       *:55628                      *:*         users:(("outline-ss-serv",pid=1568,fd=13))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @user535733 I have just edited the main-first post, and add at the end, the output for `sudo ss -tulp` for the Lubuntu machine. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Let's rearrange the list of listening ports to include the data that you provided in your `sudo ss -tulp` output:

```
PORT      STATE APPLICATION     PID 
11393/tcp open  outline-ss-serv 1568
30630/tcp open  outline-ss-serv 1568
36629/tcp open  outline-ss-serv 1568
39457/tcp open  outline-ss-serv 1568
55628/tcp open  outline-ss-serv 1568
62408/tcp open  node            1540
```

Looks like your Lubuntu system is running a server application...so open ports for connections from clients are to be expected.

If you really want to test for open and exploitable ports on an Ubuntu system, you are welcome to do so. We welcome testers! We gently suggest starting with a stock system. An open port is not the same as an exploitable port. If you discover an open and exploitable port, please file a bug report and subscribe the Ubuntu Security Team.

Comment: Thank you @user5357733, I only downloaded Lubuntu 20.04 from here https://lubuntu.me/downloads/ Isn't should be a stock system? It could be possible that some of my commands to transorm it from a stock system to a server sysyem? I appreciate.

Comment: Can you tell me please how to find out which application acts as a server application? Thank you.

Comment: It's likely the one with the word "server" in the name.